# Stratified Random sampling in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am trying to generate random points for a survey, but I want the points to fall based on 2 polygons. I have created a polygon fishnet, and have a layer of forested habitats.  I am trying to generate points so that there is one point per grid, and so that the point falls within a forested habitat in the grid.  Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: I've not used this tool but are you aware of this [sampling tool](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ecbe1fc44f35465f9dea42ef9b63e785)? Worth a look.

Answer (score 3):

dissolve your forest as a multipart polygon

intersect with your fishnet

use the [create random point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002r000000) tool with the result of your intersection as constraining feature class, and 1 as the number of point

CreateRandomPoints_management (out_path, out_name, {constraining_feature_class}, {constraining_extent}, {number_of_points_or_field}, {minimum_allowed_distance}, {create_multipoint_output}, {multipoint_size})

Answer (score 1):

As @hornbydd  mentioned in the comments, the [Sampling Design tool](http://coastalscience.noaa.gov/projects/detail?key=185) has the ability to create stratified random samples. There is a version for ArcGIS 9 and 10. However, you would still need to intersect the two dataset as @radouxju mentioned and create a new field that combines the gridID with the forest attribute. The sampling tool allows you select a field for stratification and lets you specify the number of points in each attribute in that field.